# Is Dirichlet's function enough to prove constants like $\gamma$ irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

This function appears without any reference in the book [The Irrationals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691143420) :

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos^{2n}(m!\pi x)=\left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & : x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
       0 & : x \notin \mathbb{Q}
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

I found the name of the function to be Dirichlet's function and it got me thinking. Is this function enough to prove constants like $\gamma$ irrational?

I am a beginner when it comes to irrationality proofs, but I think this function requires one to know the entire decimal expansion of the number, $x$, in question because $m!$ goes to infinity and a decimal approximation for $x$ would eventually make the limit go to $1$...?

Comment: I don't get it. Did they give a worked example with $x$ irrational?

Comment: No, the equation was the only thing on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Right now it is unknown if $\gamma$ is irrational or not. As long there is no proof for this result, it is improbable that one can comment if a certain technique might be helpful for this....